# Is it possible to sensibly render a url.URL value within a struct inside a template?

Tags: go

I have a struct that has a `url.URL` *value* as one of its (many) fields. I'm trying to pass an instance of that struct to an `html/template` and have it render those fields, including the URL, in a sensible way.

Consider this example code:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/url"
    "os"
)

var tmpl *template.Template = template.Must(
    template.New("").Parse(`<a href="{{ .URL }}">{{ .Text }}</a>` + "\n"),
)

type pointer struct {
    Text string
    URL  *url.URL // pointer, which is rendered sensibly
}

type value struct {
    Text string
    URL  url.URL // value, which is not rendered sensibly
}

func main() {
    u := url.URL{Scheme: "https", Host: "google.com", Path: "/path"}
    pointer := pointer{Text: "pointer", URL: &u}
    value := value{Text: "value", URL: u}

    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, pointer)
    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, value)
}
```

On my machine (go 1.9.1), this outputs:

```
<a href="https://google.com/path">pointer</a>
<a href="%7bhttps%20%20%3cnil%3e%20google.com%20/path%20%20false%20%20%7d">value</a>
```

On [the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Zflnn0QgKjx), this outputs:

```
<a href="https://google.com/path">pointer</a>
<a href="
** Signal 11 from untrusted code: pc=630b0008b020

Program exited.
```

What's the best way to have `html/template` render a `url.URL` **value** that's a field of a passed-struct “normally”?

(Ideally I'd only change the template, or possibly use something in a `FuncMap`. I'd also ideally like to avoid either having to create a bunch of almost-identical structs that have `*url.URL`s instead of `url.URL`s, or having to fill a map with the struct's fields and pass *that* to the template.)

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/PtPNvQV9vNc If you want one function for both, have it accept an interface and then type assert.

Comment: Every method and constructor of `net.URL` uses pointers. Why are you using values?

Comment: @Adrian: these structs are backed by a database so it seemed sensible, but you make an excellent point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the template engine will not take the address of a value to find a `String() string` method.

One workaround is to use a FuncMap:

```
func urlstr(u url.URL) string {
    return u.String()
}

var tmpl *template.Template = template.Must(
    template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{"urlstr": urlstr}).Parse(`<a href="{{urlstr .URL}}">{{ .Text }}</a>` + "\n"),
)
```

Note that the complier implicitly takes the address of `u` when calling `String() string`.

If you have a mix of `*url.URL` and `url.URL` values and don't want to worry about which kind you have in the template, then replace the function `urlstr` above with:

```
func urlstr(u interface{}) string {
    switch u := u.(type) {
    case *url.URL:
        return u.String()
    case url.URL:
        return u.String()
    default:
        panic("unexpected")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a FuncMap with a func taking a url.URL value will do it:

```
func f(u url.URL) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s-%s-%s", u.Scheme, u.Host, u.Path)
}
```

and

```
funcMap := template.FuncMap{
    "url": f,
}

var tmpl *template.Template = template.Must(
    template.New("").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(`<a href="{{ url .URL }}">{{ .Text }}</a>` + "\n"),
)
```

produces the same result for both ptr and value:

```
<a href="https-google.com-/path">pointer</a>
<a href="https-google.com-/path">value</a>
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/DMTFF3fueau

Interestingly, if f takes a ptr, it fails in the same way.

Comment: That doesn't produce a valid URL as output.